# вывод картинок из базы данных на страницу через реакт

Tags: php, reactjs

есть фронтенд реакт и бэкенд php. Вывожу данные из базы данных mysql. Все данные выводятся в localhost: 3000 кроме картинок. через php картинки из сервера выводятся. почему не  выводятся на localhost?

Comment: Можете подробнее описать? Там вставить примеры какие-то, какого поведения ожидаете и прочее

Comment: @SaNFeeD у меня картинки в базе данных с компа и адрес такой : картинка. png. Картинки лежат в папке backend и через php они выводятся. Но когда я их вывожу  на localhost:3000, не отображаются. Если я введу картинки с интернета с адресом "http://, то эти выводятся. 
Что-то не правильно с адресом, но я не могу найти правильный адрес  картинок для базы данных phpmyadmin.

Comment: Ссылки в базе данных храните относительно основного домена. Пример: домен - http://test.com, картинки лежат также в папке "backend", соответственно, чтобы получить доступ к картинке, необходимо полностью указать путь к это картинке - "http://test.com/backend/image.png". 
Поэтому в базе у вас должен храниться пусть именно к картинке - "backend/image.png". Затем на странице уже через JS добавляете доменное имя и выводите картинку

Comment: И еще не совсем понял. Как понять - "через php выводится нормально"? Вы в php через echo ссылку на картинку выводите или как? Добавьте примеры кода!

Comment: @SaNFeeD указываю путь картинок: recipe.com/static/images/suppe.png, на localhost: 3000 не выводиться, а на recipe.com все выводится.

Comment: Это я уже понял. Я говорю - пример кода добавьте! Как выводите, как получаете, как отображаете и прочее. В самом то деле... Угадывать мы долго будем

Comment: @SaNFeeD так выводится : 
   $out = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($day_res); $i++) {
        $out .= '<div>';
        $out .='<h4>'.$day_res[$i]['name'].'</h4>';
        $out .= '<p>'.$day_res[$i]['ingredients'].'</p>';
        $out .= '<p>'.$day_res[$i]['description'].'</p>';
        $out .= '<img src="/static/images/'.$day_res[$i]['image'].'" width=200>';
        $out .='</div>';
    }
    echo $out;
    echo json_encode($day_res);
}

Comment: @SaNFeeD а через реакт нет : 
  function Day() {
 const [day, setDay] = useState([]);
  fetch("http://recipe.ua", {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   },
   body: JSON.stringify()
  })
   .then (response => response.json())
   .then (response => {
    console.log(response);
    setDay(response);
   })

Comment: @SaNFeeD return (
   <div>
   {day && day.length > 0 && day.map((item, index) =>
    <li key={index}> 
    <h4>{item.name}</h4>
    <p>{item.ingredients}</p>
    <p>{item.description}</p>
     <img style={{width: "18rem"}} src={item.image} alt={item.name} /> 
    </li>)}
    </div>
  );
}  
export default Day;

Comment: @SaNFeeD сперва вам огромное спасибо за ваши ответы. Я наконец то нашла ошибку в адресе картинок в базе данных. Вы мне даже почти помогли, но забыли написать так :http://test.com/backend/image.png.

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы выводите через php. То к ссылке на картинку подставляете статическую ссылку к папке `/static/images/`, а затем уже подставляете саму картинку.

```
<img src="/static/images/'.$day_res[$i]['image'].'" width=200>
```

В реакте вы просто выводите картинку, без ссылке к папке.

```
<img style={{width: "18rem"}} src={item.image} alt={item.name} />
```

Чтобы получить картинку в реакте нужно подставить ссылку. Вывод картинки будет такой:

```
<img style={{width: "18rem"}} src={'/static/images/' + item.image} alt={item.name} />
```

Comment: не выводит, уже пробовала так, я в отчаяние

Comment: Откройте консоль в браузере и посмотрите, что там пишет?

Comment: все отлично, спасибо вам. Ошибка : я не добавила в начале пути http